# django/python: How does python encode non-English characters

Tags: python, encoding

I am dealing with some string manipulation and try to put them into database. Then I encountered this(I believe it's german):

```
Sichere Administration von VoIP-EndgerÃ¤ten
```

After I put it into database, I realized that the non-English characters became:

```
Sichere Administration von VoIP-Endger\u00e4ten
```

and when I fetch it from database and passed this string to subprocess.Popen(), it gives error:

```
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

My question is: How did this happen? Also does anybody have any useful references about how to learn encoding/decoding stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html); you are dealing with encoded and unicode text.

The first string is UTF-8 data being interpreted as Latin-1, the second string is a unicode string and cannot be passed to `Popen()` without encoding first:

```
>>> print u'\u00e4'  # A unicode escape code for the latin-1 character ä
ä
>>> u'\u00e4'.encode('utf8')  # The same character encoded to UTF-8
'\xc3\xa4'
>>> print u'\u00e4'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')  # Misinterpreted as Latin-1
Ã¤
```

You'll need to figure out what encoding your external process can handle and call `.encode()` on your data before passing it to `.Popen()`.